# FlatButton height to titleLabel

Tags: cosmicmind

I'm trying to make the height of a FlatButton to the height of the label inside the FlatButton.

```
var textButton: FlatButton = FlatButton()
textButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

But that does only get rid of the spacing on the left and right. There is still spacing on top and bottom. How can I make the button no bigger than the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bug in ios, but this is a workaround:

```
var textButton: FlatButton = FlatButton()
textButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 0)
```

This actually makes the button smaller than if I do

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: , right: 0)
```